# "find" exclude by fstype strange behavior

Tags: filesystems, find, proc

I try to have "find" command exclude "/proc" filesystem. 
I would prefer a portable solution to be able to use it on non GNU based hosts (oldest AIX for instance, where "find" do not have the "-path" option)

Here's what I've tried (on a Linux host) and a partial filtered output:

```
$  find /  ! -fstype proc   >/dev/null
find: `/proc/9475/task/9535/fdinfo/7': No such file or directory
find: `/proc/10856': No such file or directory
find: `/proc/10856': No such file or directory
find: `/proc/10858': No such file or directory
find: `/proc/10858': No such file or directory
find: `/proc/15650': No such file or directory
find: `/proc/15650': No such file or directory
find: `/proc/15654': No such file or directory
find: `/proc/15654': No such file or directory
find: `/proc/15656': No such file or directory
find: `/proc/15656': No such file or directory
find: `/proc/15657': No such file or directory
find: `/proc/15657': No such file or directory
find: `/proc/15663': No such file or directory
etc ....
```

I don't understand why "find" keep walking inside the "/proc" file system despite of the "! -fstype proc" switch?

Answer (score 8):

As [terdon explained](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/471617/116858), `find` will still enter the `/proc` directory, but it will not return any pathnames from that filesystem type.

To remove any search path as soon as the `proc` filesystem type is detected, use

```
find / -fstype proc -prune -o -print
```

However, since you're wanting to do this on an old `find`, the `-fstype` option may not be available.  If `-path` (a standard option of `find`) is also not available, then it begins to be a bit difficult to come with suggestions as the implementation is clearly not POSIX compliant.

One option *could* be to use `-xdev` which would cause `find` to stay strictly in the same filesystem as the starting path.  You would then have to run one `find` for each filesystem that you want to examine. There could also be an option called `-x` (as on BSD systems) which acts like `-xdev`.

If that too is not possible, then you may have to resort to using `-type d -name proc -prune` to disregard all directories that are called `proc`.

Comment: `-path` (originally a BSD extension, GNU find initially had `-wholename` later changed to `-path` IIRC) is a relatively recent (2008) addition to POSIX. You can also use `-exec test  /proc = {} \;`, though that would be very inefficient.

Comment: the "-prune" approach was my initial option, but unfortunately "proc" file system type is "procfs" on AIX and "proc" un Linux
And  unfortunately, aix dont like this:

`$ find /  \( -fstype proc -o   -fstype procfs \) -prune | head` give the following error:
`find: invalid filesystem type proc`

Comment: @GillesPion Then you would have to rely on the name of the directory, unless you detect the operating system type beforehand and call `find` in specific ways for each operating system.

Answer (score 5):

The `-fstype` directive tells `find` not to return any results that are on that filesystem type. That, however, doesn't mean that it won't look at the `/proc` directory. It simply means that it won't return files found on a `proc` filesystem. However, it still needs to go through the `/proc` directory since there is no way of knowing whether something, a non-proc filesystem, has been mounted onto `/proc/something`. For instance, on my Arch, I find:

```
$ find /proc ! -fstype proc -printf '%p %F\n' 2>/dev/null 
/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc binfmt_misc
/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/CLR binfmt_misc
/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/register binfmt_misc
/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/status binfmt_misc
```

This is because `/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/` is not a proc filesystem:

```
$ mount | grep proc
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=51,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=12642)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,relatime)
```

So there are two mountpoints under `/proc` which hold non-proc filesystems.

So, with this in mind, note that your question only shows error messages. None of those files have actually been returned by `find`, so it would seem to be behaving as expected. It goes through the files in `/proc` but doesn't consider them matches if they're on a `proc` filesystem.

Comment: instead of "won't return files found there" maybe "won't return files of type proc that are found there" ?

Comment: @JeffSchaller I'm trying to weasel out of giving any details because I have only a vague understanding of `/proc`. Feel even more free than usual to make any improvements.

Comment: intermediate update: /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc may be a separate filesystem from /proc

Comment: I'd add that the OP is seeing those errors because `find` enumerated /proc before investigating the file types; once it tried to `stat` them, they were gone (process exited).

Comment: `binfmt_misc` is simply mounted on a directory inside `/proc` (you can see that with `mount | grep binfmt`; there's nothing special about it, you can simply mount any filesystem you like on any directory you like eg. `mkdir -p fake_dir; echo systemd666 > fake_dir/comm; mount --bind fake_dir /proc/1`